# Get all strings that occur in ALL given lists

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-7

I have a list of lists: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names` 
I want to get a list of all Strings that occur in every list. Is there an easier and more elegant way to do this instead of using 4 loops:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<String> n1 : names) {
    for (String name1 : n1) {
        for (ArrayList<String> n2 : names) {
            for (String name2 : n2) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

I want a list of Strings that occur all lists. So if a String is in only one or two of the lists, it should not be in my result list.

Yes the code must be compatible to Java 7, so sadly no streams.

Comment: Do you want to flatten the list of lists into a single list? Do you also want to avoid repeated elements?

Comment: You've tagged Java-7 - I assume therefore you don't want a `stream`?

Comment: You want the intersection of the lists?

Comment: can java 8 be an option (you tagged the question as java-7) ?

Comment: In java8 you would do something like _names.stream().map(List::stream).reduce(Stream::concat);_
In java7 you could try doing the same with https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

Comment: It's not clear at all by reading your question whether you want the intersection or the union of the lists. Please clarify

Comment: I added some comment, hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get help of [`ArrayList.retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) on Java 7. For example, having this lists in `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> names`:

```
list1 = "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"
list2 = "e6", "e7", "e3", "e4", "e5"
list3 = "e8", "e9", "e3", "e4", "e5"
```

you can use `retainAll` to get all Strings that occur in every list (the intersection):

```
List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(list1);
for(List<String> tmpList: names){
    commonElements.retainAll(tmpList);
}
```

Output:

> [e3, e4, e5]

Comment: Whilst OP has currently neglected to clarify whether it's union or intersection; this looks most likely what they want.

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten multiple Lists into a single List of Strings

Java 7:

```
List<String> flattenedResult = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> currentNameList : names) {
    flattenedResult.addAll(currentNameList);
}
```

Using Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> flattenedResult = names.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```